# Gmail/groups mails delayed for long periods or lost

Tags: gmail, google-groups

A club I'm a committee member of use Google mail + Google groups to correspond & organise. We have a group e-mail address that forwards mail to everyone else on the group

We've been plagued with problems whereby some members of the group either don't see group mails for a long time, or at all. Likewise, sometimes mails don't come through from certain people for a long time or at all.

There's no specific pattern to it and we don't get error messages back or see stuff diverted to spam folders or anything.

The committee are diverse in terms of mail usage - some use the web, some use forwarding, some use pop/imap, mobile app, etc. and I couldn't point to a specific person or use case that always has issues.

Has anyone experienced this? Is there anything I can do test-wise to try and diagnose it?

The question has also been asked if there's an alternative (free or paid) that we could move to, but I don't know of anything that's any better than Google's offering (we deserted Yahoo groups for Google) and I don't see that upgrading to "G Suite" or whatever they call it would make the service any speedier or more reliable.